# Cartesian coordinates on 2 circles

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

What are the coordinates of points $j$ and $k$ in terms of $a$, $b$, and $c$?

[image: question image]

The curves are circular arcs with the center of the circles at $y = 0$.

Comment: Please include all relevant information in the body of your Question.  Here the crucial fact that the curves are *circular arcs* is only alluded to in the title.  The connection is better stated explicitly in the body of the Question for your Readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(copying and editing John's answer, since the edit to that answer was rejected)

The line from $j$ through $k$ passes through the circle center which is on the $x$-axis; let's say it's at $(R+a, 0)$, so that $R$ is the radius of the inner circle.

The angle from the negative $x$ axis clockwise to the line $jk$, the acute angle in this picture...let's call that $t$ (radians). Then 
$$
Rt = c \\
(R+a)t = b
$$
Hence
$$
c + at = b,
$$
and we get
$$
t = \frac{b-c}{a}.
$$
We also see that 
$$
R = \frac{c}{t} = \frac{ca}{b-c}.
$$

The location of point $k$ is then 
$$
k = (R+a, 0) + R(-\cos t, \sin t)
$$
and for point $j$, we have
$$
j = (R+a, 0) + (R+a) (-\cos t, \sin t).
$$

If we want these in terms of only $a$, $b$, and $c$ then
$$
k = (\frac{ca}{b-c}+a, 0) + \frac{ca}{b-c}(-\cos \frac{b-c}{a}, \sin \frac{b-c}{a}) \\
j = (\frac{ca}{b-c}+a, 0) + (\frac{ca}{b-c}+a) (-\cos \frac{b-c}{a}, \sin \frac{b-c}{a})
$$

Answer (score 1):

The line from $i$ through $j$ passes through the circle center which appears, from the drawing, to be on the $x$-axis; let's say it's at $(R+a, 0)$, so that $r$ is the radius of the inner circle.

The angle from the negative $x$ axis clockwise to the line $ij$, the acute angle in this picture...let's call that $t$. Then 
$$
Rt = c \\
(R+a)t = b
$$
Hence
$$
c + at = d,
$$
and we get
$$
t = \frac{b-c}{a}.
$$
We also see that 
$$
R = \frac{c}{t} = \frac{ca}{b-c}.
$$

The location of point $k$ is then 
$$
k = (R+a, 0) + R(-\cos t, \sin t)
$$
and for point $j$, we have
$$
j = (R+a, 0) + (R+a) (-\cos t, \sin t).
$$

Comment: is d meant to be b?

Comment: Yes; replace all "$d$"s by $b$s.

Comment: ...and the center of the circles is (R + a, 0).  Isn't that what the beginning of the last two expressions should be? (instead of (R, 0))

Comment: I'm submitted corrections with the edit button.

Comment: And I've now performed the edits....sorry about those mistakes; I was typing fast before I had to run off and do something.